# Changing ReturnUrl in OWIN RedirectToIdentityProvider notification

Tags: security, authentication, owin, katana, ws-federation

We are currently overriding [`WSFederationAuthenticationModule.RedirectToIdentityProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.services.wsfederationauthenticationmodule.redirecttoidentityprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) in our product to change the returnUrl to which the users agent is redirected to after authentication.

Now we're in the proces of adopting OWIN (Katana) middleware instead of HttpModules. In the [`RedirectToIdentityProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation.WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications.RedirectToIdentityProvider);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) notification in `WsFederationAuthenticationOptions`, I see the `WCtx` parameter now contains a `WsFedOwinState` parameter which is encrypted using DPAPI.

How do I implement the `RedirectToIdentityProvider` action to change the return URL? Do I need to decrypt the `WsFedOwinState` parameter to add the returnUrl query parameter or is there some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inside RedirectToIdentityProvider, you will have access to the WsFederationMessage.

Set the Wreply property to the value you need.

As a note: MachineKey is used by default, not DPAPI for protecting wctx.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I thought wreply was only used for wsignout1.0. Do you know why this changed?

Comment: Have a look at: http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/v1.2/os/ws-federation-1.2-spec-os.html. See sections 13.2.2 and 13.2.4.1  wreply is defined fo Sign-out and Sign-in messages.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed the return URL in `SecurityTokenValidated` and had the redirection from ADFS always go to the same URL

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { AuthenticationType = WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType });

    app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Wtrealm = realm,
        MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata,
        Notifications = new WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            SecurityTokenValidated = nx =>
            {
                nx.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.RedirectUri = "/RedirectionGoesHere.aspx";
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
    });
    // This makes any middleware defined above this line run before the Authorization rule is applied in web.config
    app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
}
```